# JS object method call not working from callback

Tags: javascript, object, callback, prototype, ajaxform

I have a small problem with prototyped JS coding, and with callbacks. It looks like not working properly.

Here is my sample:

```
var hl = new HeaderLogin;
hl.drawPanel();

var HeaderLogin = function(elem) {
    this.init = true;
    this.jsvh    = JSViewHandler.getInstance();
};


HeaderLogin.prototype.drawPanel = function() {
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.jsvh.get({
        ...
        'callback': function(rsp, templates) {
            ...
            $('#jsview_user_login_form').ajaxForm({success: asd});
        }
    });
    function asd(rspJSON, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        self.showResponse(rspJSON, statusText, xhr, $form);
    }
};

HeaderLogin.prototype.showResponse = function(rspJSON, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    if (typeof this.init === 'undefined') {
        alert('not an object');
    }
    ...
}
```

I have to call the `showResponse` function after the form has been sent, but if I use the `{success: self.showResponse}` the `init` will not exists. It looks like a static call and I can't access any variable from the constructor. If I create a local `asd` function and I use it as the success callback the `showRespons` will know about the constructor variables.

I don't want to use this extra function, if you have any solution about this problem, please let me know!

Thanks a lot guys! :)

**SOLUTION:**

**success: self.showResponse.bind(self)**

Comment: var hl = new HeaderLogin();

Comment: Try `success: self.showResponse.bind(self)`

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this in a long time, but can you try with

```
'callback': function(rsp, templates) {
    ...
    var s = self;
    $('#jsview_user_login_form').ajaxForm({success: s.showResponse});
}
```

Comment: Nope, I already tried it: `var self = this, self___ = self;` and `self___.showResponse` but I got the same problem. :)